# Road Area in the Middle of the Land

Tags: geometry

I came across this question while studying. It goes like this:

A region of land, 50 m by 40 m is to cross diagonally by a road 15 meters wide as shown in the figure

[image]

What's the road area?"

My work:  I don't know how to approach this. It seems silly that I couldn't answer it.

How do you answer it though?

Comment: See https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101016204900AAaZgzZ

Answer (score 1):

[image: The picture]

See this picture. I am saying Ar(Shape)=Area of the the Shape.

You need to find the area of road. Then Area of road=Ar(ABCD)-2Ar(APS)

**Steps to solve the problem:**

Note that, ABC is similar to APS, APS is similar to PBQ and APS is similar to DSR.

And $\angle$SDR=$\angle$PSA=$\angle$BPQ.

Now you know the following lengths: PQ=SR.

Then you can easily find Ar(APS) using the lengths AB,AD,PQ.